# Update Probability When Stage is Selected

Tags: visualforce

I`m working on dynamic VF page which will show fields based on stages selected. Page works fine but the issue is with Probability field. While selecting Stage, Probability field does not show up value % associated at each level (like it generates for standard SF Opportunity page). Can someone please help? Its an urgent requirement.

I already tried this solution but cant get it to work. Page no longer refreshes to show relevant fields and probability also not generating.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="True" id="page" >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Opportunity" subtitle="{!opportunity.name}"/>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" />
<script src="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";

    function processChange(){

        var obj = document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.frm.thePageBlock.pbs.stageFieldId}');
        var p = document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.frm.thePageBlock.pbs.probabilityFieldId}');

        var qr = sforce.connection.query("Select DefaultProbability From OpportunityStage where MasterLabel = '" + $(obj).val() + "'") ; 
        records = qr.getArray("records");

        for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
            var record = records[i];
            $(p).val(record.DefaultProbability);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

<apex:form id="frm">


    <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Opportunity" id="thePageBlock" mode="edit">



        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>                
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:actionRegion >
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs" title="Basic Information" columns="1">


                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.name}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Stage"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel >
              <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}" onchange="processChange()" id="stageFieldId" >
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock" 
                                                status="status"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Probability}" id="probabilityFieldId"/>     

                        </apex:inputField>
                        <apex:actionStatus startText="applying value..." id="status"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.amount}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.closedate}"/>


            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:actionRegion>

                    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Closed Lost Information" columns="1"
                               rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Prospecting'}">
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Description}"  required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Type}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.DeliveryInstallationStatus__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Languages__c}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Closed Lost Information" columns="1"
                               rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Closed Lost'}">
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Primary_Competitor__c}"  required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Reason_Lost__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.OrderNumber__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.TrackingNumber__c}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>



    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Comment: You're more likely to get a useful response if you tell people what you tried in terms of the JS and JQuery from the page you've referenced (which you didn't include in the above code) along with what didn't work for you with it, rather than just posting your code and saying "please tell me how to fix it".

Comment: Sorry for the brevity. Here is the code that doesn't work. Page no longer refreshes to show relevant fields and probability also not generating. I updated the question! Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

There's no automatic way to do this as far as I can see.  You can do it the old fashion way by creation a partial page update and querying/updating the probability value based on the stage.

1) Create an extension to your VF

2) Add **actionSupport** to the Stage field with `action="{!changeStageName}"`

3) Make sure the propability field is in the rendered/rerendered area

4) In your extension class, make sure to make the method **changeStageName**

5) Set the probability based on stage chose  by query the Sales process (**OpportunityStage**).

[This link](http://opfocus.com/blog/dynamically-updating-probability-when-selecting-stage-with-visualforce-2/) has example codes so I am not going to paste them again.